# About precision on C++ calculus

Tags: c++, floating-point, precision, calculus

I have gotten a prototype function that make some calculus (integrals of gamma function) in C++ and I need to convert it to C language. The author used float variables with suffix f in every calculus. Like these sentences...

```
float a1=.083333333f;
float vv=dif*i/1.414214f;
```

The program makes use of truncated series on many lines by multiplication of some of that variables.
My question so is... Don`t I get more precision if I use double precision variables? Why the sufix could be necessary on that case?
Thanks in advance!

Comment: "Don`t I get more precision if I use double precision variables?" Certainly... it seems the author valued performance/memory over precision. Which can be more or less reasonable, depending on what this will be used for.

Comment: Actually, the example is rather bad style. Any proper compiler should optimize `1./12` to exactly the same as `.0833333333`, and even `sqrt(2)` can be calculated at compile-time. It's particularly bad in C++, where you can make this perfectly generalized for both `double` and `float`, even by simply using a template definition.

Comment: BTW, the code is valid for both C and C++.  Double precision can be obtained by changing `float` to `double` and removing 'f' from the numbers (a floating point literal is double precision by default).

Comment: I just asked that question because I have heard about some cases that the use of floating type literal is better in precision than the double type... Don`t ask me when! But thanks for attention of all!

Answer (score 0):

You would get more precision with double precision, and you don't need any special suffix in C/C++. So, your code could look like

```
  double a1=.083333333;
  double vv=dif*i/1.414214;
```

Also, you are free to use more accurate floating-point literals if you want... so add more "3"s and expand "1.414214" to your heart's content. Bear in mind, however, that not even doubles are perfectly accurate.

Answer (score 0):

float, in modern systems, is a 32 bit floating point type.
double, in modern systems, is a 64 bit floating point type.

The accuracy of a float is much less than a 64 bit floating point, but is still very useful for speed and because it occupies less bytes of ram.

Now with 64 bit system the difference between float and double are a lot less noticeable, but in the past, they could be really different.

You have always to find a trade-off between performance and precision: the choice between double and float is exactly this: do you want high precision or low precision but better performance?

In 3D games usually we use float, in calculus applications we usually use double.

See if the precision of double suits you, if not, i would suggest you to search a C++ library for numbers with abritrary precision, though, to continue our discussion about performances, the performances of this objects are really bad compared to native double or float.

Comment: "with 64 bit system the difference between float and double are a lot less noticeable"... I don't know what system you're talking about, but this isn't true on the most popular ones.